# ASP.NET C# partial class in separate files not working CS1061

Tags: asp.net, partial

I have an asp.net page called prequal.aspx with a codebehind of prequal.aspx.cs. It works. I want to separate out each client code from this page into their own partial files (to reduce chance of modifying the wrong one by mistake later.) Both .cs files begin as such:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

    public partial class prequal : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
```

When I put one of the clients code into its own file, it compiles fine but I get the following error when I try to view the page:

CS1061: 'ASP.prequal_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'lnkLanguage_Click' and no extension method 'lnkLanguage_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.prequal_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

prequal.aspx has this:

`<asp:LinkButton id="lnkLanguage" onclick="lnkLanguage_Click" runat="server" CausesValidation="False">English / En Español</asp:LinkButton>`

prequal.aspx.cs has this:

```
    protected void lnkLanguage_Click()
    {
        // alternate preferred language
        if (Session["lang"].ToString() == "spa")
        {
            Session["lang"] = "eng";
        }
        else
        {
            Session["lang"] = "spa";
        }
        populateQuestions();
    }
```

populateQuestions() will call other code in prequal.aspx.cs which calls code in prequal-client1.aspx.cs. The code works before I split it up so am I going about creating separate partial class files incorrectly?  Or is the issue something else that I am unaware of yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the signature for `lnkLanguage` has to be:

```
protected void lnkLanguage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //...
}
```

Comment: Initially it was like that but since no parameters are directly passed to it, I had removed that. Putting it back in still yields the same result.

Comment: Are you pre-compiling this site in advance?  I'm thinking maybe ASP.NET is just looking at the `CodeBehind` attribute on the page directive and just compiling that one `.cs` file.  You might be best to compile all the .CS code behind files into a DLL in the bin directory.

Comment: @HankKnah How would nothing be passed to it? .NET Framework Guidelines require you to handle the method signature that Mike posted. Since buttons are a native .NET control they will adhere to this signature.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @FrazellThomas - Correct, as delegates are type-safe in .NET, they will only bind with the correct signature.  However, I'm thinking in this case something is stuck in temporary Internet files, or it's some sort of page directive issue where not all the right `.cs` files are being compiled in.

Comment: I've readded "object sender, EventArgs e" to all the routines. Clean Solution, Build Solution, review prequal.aspx in a new browser tab....same result. There is no bin directory in this projects folder (or in any other project folders). Other ideas?

Comment: Oops, yes, there is a bin folder. Looks like it has one .dll for this project, a program debug database file and two microsoft .dll files.

Comment: (as found in other similar questions) I have tried adding a namespace to both .cs files, same result. The routines are not "private" and prequal.aspx is:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="prequal" Codebehind="prequal.aspx.cs" %> The error says there is no definition for 'lnkLanguage_Click', and yet, immediately find it in a copy and search.

Comment: When I remove the offending line of code, the same error jumps to the first OnSelectedIndexChanged I have for a radio button. When I comment out the offending line of code with <!-- --> around the LinkButton, it still gives me the SAME error (even though it is now a comment).

Comment: Resolution: I put the split-off code back into the original file (and commented it out in the extra file) and still got the same error. At some point in the splitting-off process, I had "Exclude from Project" of the main prequal.aspx.cs file (for what at this point I don't remember). I re-included the file and all worked. Moved code back out to its own file and it still works. I am fairly certain I did not exclude this file until after I was trying to track the error, so not sure at what point it started but it has at least ended. Hope this helps out others with similar problem in the future.